# Exporting data frames in layout into unique PDF for each using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, pdf, data-frame

I have an MXD with 2 data frames.

How can I export each Dataframe as a separate PDF?

Comment: Move one off the layout page, export, then swap.

Comment: Create separate layouts.

Answer (score 1):

Your best option is to do this outside of ArcMap in some sort of image processing software.  Another trick that you may want to consider is "hiding" one dataframe underneath or placing it outside of the page altogether and selecting "Clip Output to Graphics Extent" when exporting.